# How to free up some cache space in [ Flutter ]

Tags: flutter, dart, caching

Well, I am using [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager) to cache my files.

Now I have a requirement like If my app's cache memory is full, I have to clear up some space in my cache.

Is there any possible way to do that so?

Thanks in advance.

Note: I can Clear my cache by using `await DefaultCacheManager().emptyCache();` and it's clear all the files from the cache. I don't want to clear all the files. I need to free up some space.

Comment: Why you need to do that manually ?In the cache manager you can set the file limit or stalePeriod, which will automatically handle it. Or if your cache memory is full the OS will clean the cache.

Comment: I am in a critical situation like for an operation I need to store only 256kb data in the cache then if the cache is full my operation keep failing.

Comment: If that 256kb is your most important data, just call the emptyCache before setting or assigning that important data.

Comment: yes, my 256KB and cached data both are important, so I can't simply call `emptyCache`. but your first comment helped me to think another way. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you can only remove one or all files from cache, you can just delete the oldest cache files instead to free space.

this is done automatically according to the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager#when-are-the-cached-files-updated).

> The cache manager uses 2 variables to determine when to delete a file, the maxNrOfCacheObjects and the stalePeriod. The cache knows when files have been used latest. When cleaning the cache (which happens continuously), the cache deletes files when there are too many, ordered by last use, and when files just haven't been used for longer than the stale period.

if you want to delete the caches before it gets full then you have to refer to the older cache and delete manually.

Comment: but how could i know if there is no space in cache?